Deriving the Variance of a Posterior Conditional Probability Density Function



  
  Deriving the variance of a conditional probability density function


I am trying to derive the variance of a conditional probability density function $ p_{r_s|x,y_s} $ given by:
$$ p_{r_s|x,y_s} = \frac{e^{-\lambda r_s - \frac{(y_s - \frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4}x)^2}{2}}}{e^{-0.5 y_s^2} \left(\frac{2}{8 \rho_s^2 x^2}\right)^{9/8} \Gamma\left(\frac{9}{8}\right) + e^{-\lambda r_c}} $$
where $ p_{r_s} = \lambda e^{-\lambda r_s} $ is the prior distribution of $ r_s $, and $ p_{y_s|r_s,x} = \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4}x, 1\right) $ is the conditional distribution of $ y_s $ given $ r_s $ and $ x $.
I need to find the variance $ \text{Var}(r_s | x, y_s) $ of this conditional PDF $ p_{r_s|x,y_s} $ in closed-form.
Can someone help me derive this variance, either approximately or exactly, without resorting to numerical methods?
Thank you!

What is $r_c$ and what are the ranges of $\rho_s$ and $x$?
